# JAVA: Confusion with correct for-loop iteration?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, iteration

**Background Information:**

I am writing a program where I am supposed to graph a data set, which is stored in the following file ([input file](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/14au/homework/names.txt)), called "names.txt", using the class `DrawingPanel`.

This java file allows you to create a panel of a given size, and draw shapes and lines in this panel. The problems I am encountering with my program are unrelated to the specifications and understandings of the class methods.

The data set that I am supposed to graph using this java file is configured in the following way:

[name] [gender] [ranking] [ranking] [ranking] [ranking]....etc for a total of 14 rankings.

**Example:**

Jane F 98 108 128 116 48 55 47 39 67 202 312 345 436 384

**General goal of program:**
The user is supposed to input the name and gender they would like to see graphed. The data is then graphed, rankings representing the y axis and time representing the x axis.

**My main problem** is drawing the lines that compose the graph. The lines of these graphs are drawn with the method:

```
g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

with g representing a Graphics object. Two points are necessary as two endpoints are necessary to create a line.

This for loop is responsible for printing the lines.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < SECTION_WIDTH * DECADES; j += SECTION_WIDTH){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(j, yCoordinate, i + intervalIncrease, yCoordinate2);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            intervalIncrease += SECTION_WIDTH;
            g.drawString(intervalLabel, intervalIncrease , yCoordinate);
            }            
    }
```

**SUMMARY OF PROBLEM:** The for loop above is the cause of the bugs in my program. The problem is the incorrect printing of the lines that compose the graph. This is caused by incorrect for loop iterations and conditions, which are complicated by the awkward location of the for loop and the fact that two calls of everything are necessary to correctly run the program. Despite guessing-and-checking for several hours, I cannot figure out how to manipulate the loops to make it work.

It is complicated because the drawString method is dependent on the drawLine method variables.

I've tried implementing this into my code but it hasn't worked.

**Specific Requirements and Additional Information on DrawingPanel.java:**

Please see this ([Specification](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/14au/handouts/12.html)) for specifications on *what the graph should look* like and other requirements.

***An image of what the graph should look like is also provided below.***

```
    public static void drawRanks(String line, Graphics g){
    int yearIncrease = 0;
    int intervalIncrease = 0;
    System.out.println(line);
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    String name = lineScan.next();
    String gender = lineScan.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < DECADES/2; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        int rank = lineScan.nextInt();
        int rank2 = lineScan.nextInt();
        int yCoordinate = rank/2 + 25;
        int yCoordinate2 = rank2/2 + 25;
        String intervalLabel = name + " " + gender + " " + String.valueOf(rank);
        String intervalLabel2 = name + " " + gender + " " + String.valueOf(rank2);
        if (rank == 0){
            yCoordinate = 525;
        }
        if (rank2 == 0){
            yCoordinate2 = 525;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < SECTION_WIDTH * DECADES; j += SECTION_WIDTH){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(j, yCoordinate, i + intervalIncrease, yCoordinate2);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            intervalIncrease += SECTION_WIDTH;
            g.drawString(intervalLabel, intervalIncrease , yCoordinate);
            }            
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < DECADES; j++) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(STARTING_YEAR + yearIncrease), SECTION_WIDTH * j, 550);
        yearIncrease += 10;
    }  

    for (int k = DECADES * SECTION_WIDTH; k >= 0; k -= SECTION_WIDTH){
        g.drawLine(k, 0, k, 550);
    }

}
```

Image of graph produced: [image: DrawingPanel Graph]

Expected graph: [image: Expected DrawingPanel Graph]

Please feel free to comment if my explanation is unclear.
Here is where the DrawingPanel class is located, for compilation purposes, if necessary.
[DrawingPanel.java](https://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java)

**Here is an API for the methods:**

```
DrawingPanel name = new DrawingPanel(width, height);

Graphics g - name.getGraphics();

panel.setBackground(color); -  sets panel's background color

g.setColor(color); - sets Graphics pen color (like dipping a brush in paint)

g.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2); - a line from points (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)

g.drawString(text, x, y); - the given text with its lower-left corner at (x, y)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Are you missing line segments? Are the strings drawn in wrong locations? An image of what you get and what you'd expect would help here.

Comment: Can you break this down into something I can finish reading before Christmas?  Could you build the smallest possible program that exhibits your problem?  And tell us exactly what the problem is - just "my code doesn't work" isn't really good enough.

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of difficult to illustrate what exactly my problem is with just words. If you check the specification I have attached to my post, you can see an image of a graph of what it's intended to look like. I can provide an image of the current graph if it would help. Please check my post again.

Comment: I did try to explain what my problem is, but I'm not sure how to explain it without having to explain the background information first.

Comment: Please check again. I have added an image of the produced graph.

Comment: Please check the edits I have made before downvoting.

Comment: Please, please check what I have just written, and what I have just added before making assumptions.

Comment: I don't know what else to do or change. Just as much as saying "my code doesn't work" isn't good enough, which is why I added copious detail to avoid a post like that, simply downvoting and not commenting what I should change to make the post easier to understand is not helpful.

Comment: Adding more detail makes it worse, not better.  It's like presenting us with an entire encyclopaedia and asking us to find the misprint in it.

Comment: So, can you explain what `i` and `j` are in the two nested loops, and why this line - `g.drawLine(j, yCoordinate, i + intervalIncrease, yCoordinate2);` uses both of them.  It seems to me that that second X value should be something different from `i + intervalIncrease`.  But I'm not sure what.

Comment: i and j both are intended to iterate through the sections of the graph. There are a number of DECADE sections. DECADE = 14 in this case. The g.drawLine() method is dependent on pixels. There are 14 sections, and each section is 70 pixels wide, so I used the width of the total panel as the test and incremented by the width of a section, as a line begins and ends at each section. I believe that you are correct about the second X value needing to be a different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea, that you have to read the ranks in pairs, is wrong. What you have to do is draw a line from the last rank's coordinates to the current rank's coordinates. Here is my version of your method (mind you, I don't have your whole environment so I can't actually test this):

```
public static void drawRanks(String line, Graphics g){
    int yearIncrease = 0;
    System.out.println(line);
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    String name = lineScan.next();
    String gender = lineScan.next();
    int lastRank = lineScan.nextInt();
    int lastY = lastRank/2 + 25;
    if ( lastRank == 0 ) {
        lastY = 525;
    }
    int lastX = 0;

    while ( lineScan.hasNextInt() ) {
        int rank = lineScan.nextInt();

        int y = rank/2 + 25;
        if (rank == 0){
            y = 525;
        }
        int x = lastX + SECTION_WIDTH;

        String intervalLabel = name + " " + gender + " " + String.valueOf(lastRank);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y);
        g.drawString(intervalLabel,lastX,lastY);
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        lastRank = rank;

    }

    g.drawString(intervalLabel,lastX,lastY);

    for(int j = 0; j < DECADES; j++) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(STARTING_YEAR + yearIncrease), SECTION_WIDTH * j, 550);
        yearIncrease += 10;
    }  

    for (int k = DECADES * SECTION_WIDTH; k >= 0; k -= SECTION_WIDTH){
        g.drawLine(k, 0, k, 550);
    }

}
```

So at first you read the name and gender, and then you read the first rank, to give you initial coordinates.

Then, in every iteration of the loop, you read just one rank. You draw the line from your previous rank to your new rank. You draw the label that belongs to the previous rank at the previous rank's coordinates. And then you save your current `x`,`y` and `rank` to the `lastX`, `lastY` and `lastRank` respectively, so that you can rely on them in the next iteration.

After the loop is done, you still have one label you haven't drawn so you draw that, and then you go on to draw the black lines (I haven't looked into the correctess of your code there, just left it as is).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, this solution worked perfectly.